# .htaccess RedirectMatch alternative to cover all possible variants

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any better method to use .htaccess Redirect than my current solution? Basically I mean using current method I have to specify all possible variants of folder paths they are basically `component/contact/` and `com_users/`. Is there some common command to cover all of them?

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/com_users/(.*) /$1

RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/en/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/en/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /en/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /en/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/en/com_users/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/en/com_users(.*) /$1

RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/fi/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/fi/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /fi/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /fi/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/fi/com_users/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/fi/com_users(.*) /$1

RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/ru/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/ru/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /ru/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /ru/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/ru/com_users/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/ru/com_users(.*) /$1

RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/zh/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/zh/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /zh/component/contact/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /zh/component/contact(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/zh/com_users/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/zh/com_users(.*) /$1
## End - Custom redirects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex you can combine multiple rules into one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index\.php/(?:(?:en|fi|ru|zh)/)?(?:component/contact|com_users)/?(.*) /$1

RedirectMatch 301 /(?:en|fi|ru|zh)/component/contact/?(.*) /$1
```